# Node.js code problem

Tags: events, node.js

I am new to node.js. I am having a few problems in the code i am trying. Take a look at the code:

```
var http =require('http');
var url = require('url');
var events=require('events');
var e=new events.EventEmitter();

var i=0;
var clientlist=new Array();

function user(nam,channel) {
this.nam = nam;
this.chan=channel;
}

server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
res.write('welcome');

var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
pathname=pathname.substring(1);
pathnames=pathname.split("&");
var c=new user(pathnames[0],pathnames[1]);
clientlist[i++]=c;

console.log("user "+pathnames[0]+" joined channel "+pathnames[1]);

e.emit('userjoined',clientlist[i-1].nam,clientlist[i-1].chan);

e.on('userjoined',function(n,c) {
res.write("new user joined with name: "+n+" and he joined channel "+c+"\n");
});

});
server.listen(2000);
```

The problems i am having are:

1. I dont get a welcome message in browser for this line of code: res.write("welcome"); But,i get the console.log() message below it in the terminal
2. The userjoined event that i emitted is not caught. but, after i close the server, everything happens at once. I get the welcome message in the browser, and the callback for the userjoined event.

Can someone tell me what is going wrong here? Thanks

Comment: are you calling respond.end and I'm missing it? You have to tell it to write the stream to the browser instead of buffering it.

Comment: I do not want to call response.end() bcoz that will close off the connection. I want it to be kept alive. anyways, the problem seems to be with node0.5.0 version. The same code works in node0.4.9 version :/

Comment: Are you trying to use a socket? You still have to tell the server to send info to the client every so often. A flush at the very least.

Comment: @jcolebrand: I am not using sockets. What i am trying to do is, keep the connection open and send data to client whenever an event occurs. i looked into socket.io, but for some reason,i couldn't even get the hello world program to work. The socket.io documentation is highly inconsistent. do u think its a better option?

Comment: Yes, I know it is for what you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok there are several issues:

1. you need to declare the e.on userjoined before you call it
2. you need a res.end() in the e.on userjoined.

Here is the code fixed:

```
var http =require('http');
var url = require('url');
var events=require('events');
var e=new events.EventEmitter();

var i=0;
var clientlist=new Array();

function user(nam,channel) {
this.nam = nam;
this.chan=channel;
}

e.on('userjoined',function(res,n,c) {
console.log("iuser "+pathnames[0]+" joined channel "+pathnames[1]);
res.write("new user joined with name: "+n+" and he joined channel "+c+"\n");
res.end();
});

server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
res.write('welcome');

var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
pathname=pathname.substring(1);
pathnames=pathname.split("&");

var c=new user(pathnames[0],pathnames[1]);
clientlist[i++]=c;

console.log("user "+pathnames[0]+" joined channel "+pathnames[1]);

e.emit('userjoined',res,clientlist[i-1].nam,clientlist[i-1].chan);

});
server.listen(2000);
```

Comment: The problem is bcoz if response.end. but, I dont want to call response.end bcoz that will close the connection. This problem occurs in node0.5.0 only ... Not in node0.4.9